# $a,b,c,d$ such that $a^n=b^n=c^n=d^n=1$ and $a+b+c+d=1$

Tags: complex-numbers

Natural number $n$ is said to be Beautiful if there exists four complex number $a,b,c,d$ such that
$a^n=b^n=c^n=d^n=1$ and $a+b+c+d=1$ . Show that there exists beautiful number and explain whether 28 is beautiful or not

I'm more concerned with how I can derive this problem

Comment: A complex number $z$ is said to be an $n$th root of unity if $z^n = 1$; so really all that line says is $a,b,c,d$ are $n$th roots of unity. There's nothing to derive, really, it's basically just the definition

Comment: For existence, you can say $n=0$ and $a=-\omega$, $b=-a^2$, $c=a^3$ and $d=-a^4$ where $\omega = \exp{\frac{2i\pi}{5}}$. In fact, the sufficient and necessary conditions for your problem is that $n\equiv 0\mod 5$, if $a,b,c,d$ are distinct. (Otherwise it's just adjusting the norm) Have fun proving this!

Comment: If 0 is allowed then any four numbers adding up to 1 like all $1 \over 4$s will do the job so I think the natural number must refer to starting from 1.

Comment: Roots of order $5$ of $-1$

Comment: Yes looks like $n=10$ works. To prove that's the only case seems not so easy.

Comment: $a=b=1, c,d$ the other roots of unity of order $3$ works if we allow the numbers to repeat

Comment: $i,-i,\exp(i\pi/3),\exp(-i\pi/3)$

Comment: @Empy2 that's interesting! It might not be a necessary condition to have $n\equiv 0\mod 5$